# Attach event with dynamic conten with the help of jquery

Tags: events, bind, jquery

i have table with 4 rows and when i click on any row then a new is getting added just after row where i clicked. here i am giving my code just to show how i achieve it with jquery.

my jquery by which i adding a new row just after the row where i clicked.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
        $("table#Table1 tr").click(function () {
            var $tr = $(this).closest('tr');
            var myRow = ($tr.index() + (++counter));
            $(this).after("<tr ><td>" + myRow + ")&nbsp;</td><td><img src='Images/closelabel.png' id='imgExpandCollapse' alt='ABC' style='cursor:pointer'/></td><td>Name : New one</td><td>Desig : CEO</td></tr>");

        });
```

});

the problem is that i am adding new row with jquery but click event is not getting attach with new. so please guide me for the best approach to attach click event with new row.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to use [.live(..)](http://api.jquery.com/live/) to bind the event. This will allow dynamically generated DOM elements to use the same event.

```
$("table#Table1 tr").live( 'click', function () {
            var $tr = $(this).closest('tr');
            var myRow = ($tr.index() + (++counter));
            $(this).after("<tr ><td>" + myRow + ")&nbsp;</td><td><img src='Images/closelabel.png' id='imgExpandCollapse' alt='ABC' style='cursor:pointer'/></td><td>Name : New one</td><td>Desig : CEO</td></tr>");

        });
```

Answer (score 0):

Try changing -

```
$("table#Table1 tr").click(function () {
```

to

```
$('table#Table1 tr').live('click', function() {
```

That should ensure jQuery binds the click event to all table rows, including those that are created dynamically.

Working demo - http://jsfiddle.net/w5Atk/

Answer (score 0):

Try $.fn.delegate

http://api.jquery.com/delegate/